# VB 2008+: How to get the text of a UserControl's TextBox in a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, list, properties, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have a Visual Basic programm, where I open up a small window(frmChild) by pressing a button on the main form (frmMain). In frmChild is a FlowLayoutPanel, in which I'm adding UserControls based on the length and values of a List of Strings. The UserControl consists of a Label and a TextBox.

The "design" stuff is done(e.g. window resizing). My Problem is to get the text the user is writing in the UserControl's TextBoxes. I would like to write the Strings in a List again, to use this List in frmMain

**My UserControl Properties:**

```
Public WriteOnly Property LblTxt As String
    Set(value As String)
        Label.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property TBoxTxt As String
    Get
        Return TextBox.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        TextBox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

**The code which is adding the UserControls:**

```
    Dim z As Integer = 0

    For Each item As String In frmMain.lstNames
        Dim uC As New UserControl
        z += 1
        With uC
            .Name = "TextBox" & z
            .LblTxt = item
        End With
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(uC)
    Next
```

My Question broken down to the Main parts:

How can I get the text of a UserControl's TextBox which sits in a FlowLayoutPanel and is created in runtime?

Thanks in advance for reading :)

Edit:
I think I need something like this in my frmChild

```
For Each item As Object in FlowLayoutPanel.Controls
   lstOtherNames.Add(item.TBoxTxt) 
Next
```

Comment: doesnt `myUserControl.TBoxTxt` work?  The textbox text is public..or is the issue *finding* the usercontrols in the FLP?

Comment: You are obfuscating your question by talking about the user control.  You'd have the *exact* same problem if you added TextBoxes instead.  You can iterate FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls to find them back.  Or just not lose track of them and keep a List(Of MyUserControl).  Do consider a DataGridView instead btw.

Comment: @Plutonix yup, my issue is to find the usercontrol in the FLP, but I thought there might be an easier way to write all TextBox values in a list.

I googled much - the answers that have a bearing to my question, are mostly made for textboxes that are directly added to the FLP and it just isn't working. _.findControl_ seems to be deprecated. I can only find _.findForm_ either this is just wrong or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: So, from **where** are you trying to find them, the form code?  Your mention of `findForm` and `findControl` sounds like you want these critters to talk to each other (the hosting form surely does need to find itself)?

Comment: @Plutonix yes from my code
i need something like this:


For each Item As Object in FlowLayoutPanel
lstOtherNames.Add(Item.TextBox.Text)
Next

Comment: but **where** is the "my code" located?? surely you have code in the form as well as in the usercontrol.  It is not clear **where** you want to do this from, as I said anything like `.findform` would not be needed if "my code" is in the form.

Comment: @Plutonix sorry I misread that...
I didn't know exactly what '.findForm' is doing I just tried that to gain access to my UserControl's TextBox. I tried to use it in frmChild. Do I need this to get the text from the textboxes?
I want to have the Code (the For-Loop I wrote above, or sth. similar) in frmChild. So that I can call a function which inherits "lstOtherNames". I don't think it would make sense to place that code in a UserControl which is added many times to the FLP in frmChild.

Comment: i am still lost because you wont give any context to this.  1) "textBox" is BAD name to use for a usercontrol because they will get intermingled with regular text boxes. 2) From the form hosting the UCs, you could use `me.Controls.Find(searchName, True)` this will search CHILD controls for the name or just search the FLP's Controls collection for a name.  You could also keep the names of the UCS in a List(of String). you ought not have to FIND anything in the UC as the text is exposed as a property

Comment: @Plutonix Ok, I think I got it now - thanks. `Dim test() As Control = FLP.Controls.Find("TextBox", True)` and looping through each element with `.Text` works. Maybe I also use @HansPassant's idea with adding the controls to a list as I'm creating them and loop through this list. I think I'll create an answer by myself later. :)
And sorry, it seems that I didn't understand you correctly (I'm not a native English speaker.) :/ ... but you helped me a lot - thank you both very much :)

Still doesn't look right - but it works...better than nothing :D